# bitcoin-cli "error: couldn't connect to server"

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, client

I'm trying to connect to a `Bitcoin Core` on Windows 10. I start it with this command:

```
.\bitcoin-qt.exe --server --rest --rpcport=54352 --rpcuser=admin --rpcpassword=admin123
```

Using `netstat -an` I see that it indeed is listening on requested port

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:54352        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

However, trying to connect with `bitcoin-cli` using this command:

```
.\bitcoin-cli.exe getinfo --rpcport=54352 --rpcuser=admin --rpcpassword=admin123
```

results in this error:

```
error: couldn't connect to server
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The `--*` arguments to `bitcoin-cli` should come before the RPC command. Those arguments are for `bitcoin-cli` itself. However the position you put them in are positions for the `getinfo` RPC command and not `bitcoin-cli`. You should instead be using the following command:

```
.\bitcoin-cli.exe --rpcport=54352 --rpcuser=admin --rpcpassword=admin123 getinfo
```